# Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Tags: mysql, asp.net

When ever i run my application i m getting this error ...!!

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Comment: A little more information about your project would be helpful. Do you access MySQL after all? If so, how?

Comment: We need some more info to help you. What is the date value you are trying to convert? Also, can you share with us the piece of the code causing the exception?

Comment: Are you sure the value from MySql cannot be `null`?

Comment: Post your code. In the meantime, change your property's type to DateTime? just in case MySQL returns a NULL

Comment: Please, show your code snippet for the field reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that field value is not `NULL` by using [`IsDBNull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareadermembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-isdbnull) method then use [`GetDateTime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareadermembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-getdatetime).

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull("FieldName")) {
    d = reader.GetDateTime("FieldName");
} else {
    d = ... ; /* set default value or do something to handle issue */
}
```

Where the `d` is a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `reader` is a [`MySqlDataReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader.html).